# SUBSTRING MSSQL Обрезать строку до первого пробела

Tags: sql-server

Доброе утро! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как при помощи SUBSTRING получить со строки не фиксированное число символов, а символы до первого пробела. Т.е. со строки Иванов Иван Иванович получить только  Иванов.Спасибо

Comment: Получить позицию пробела (CHARINDEX), взять соответствующее количество символов (LEFT). Учесть, что пробела в значении может и не быть. Или, если версия позволяет - сразу STRING_SPLIT.

Answer (score 1):

Пример работы кода, который рекомендует **Akina:**

```
declare @string nvarchar (50)=N'Иванов Иван Иванович';
select @string, case when charindex(' ',@string)>0 then  left (@string, charindex(' ',@string)-1) else @string end
set @string =N'Иван';
select @string, case when charindex(' ',@string)>0 then  left (@string, charindex(' ',@string)-1) else @string end
```

[Тут фиддл](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9db948db04afd9458e12e0b132c999eb)

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!